# Can the data type "char" be treated as the data type "int"?

Tags: c, types, clang

My understanding of the data type, `char`, is that it's an integral data type and can be treated like the data type, `int`. So, can anyone explain what's wrong with the code below?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("%d", num);
}
```

I have tried to run this code using the clang compiler expecting that it will read a number and then print it again. However, after entering the number, the result was an error called "segmentation fault". Through my experience, this error is caused by the call to the `scanf()` function.

Comment: No, that's not correct. You can do it in `printf()` because of default integer promotions, but not with `scanf()` because there are no promotions for pointers.

Comment: `&num` is a pointer to 1 byte, but `%d` requires a pointer to `sizeof(int)` bytes (usually 4 or 8 bytes).

Comment: A good compiler will warn about that code.

Comment: Thank you, this clarifies every thing. But I still can use a variable of data type "char" and treat it as an "int" regardless of "scanf()" and such functions, can't I?

Comment: It's an integer type, so you can use it like an integer in expressions. E.g. `num + 3` is fine.

Comment: If you're not actually using it to hold a character, you just want a small integer, it's better to use a type like `int8_t` or `uint8_t` to make this clear.

Comment: Thanks again. But what is the benefit of using "int8_t" instead of "char" or "uint8_t" instead of "unsigned char"?

Comment: It makes your intentions clearer. The name `char` sounds like it's being used to hold printing characters, not numbers.

Comment: You want to make sure your `char` is signed ... and `if (scanf("%hhd", &num) != 1) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`. See https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my understanding of the data type "char" is that it's an integral data type and can be treated like the data type "int"

`char` is among C's integer types, yes.  Because it *is* an integer type, it can be treated in all ways like an integer type.  But that's not the same as being treated like `int` in particular, which is a different integer type.  `char` can be treated in *some* ways like `int`, but it is not interchangeable with `int`.

> Can anyone explain what's wrong with this code?
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int main()
> {
> char num;
> scanf("%d", &num);
> printf("%d", num);
> }
> ```

Its behavior is undefined on account of the expression `&num` not being correctly type matched with the `scanf` conversion specifier `%d`.  This is one of the ways in which `char` is not interchangeable with `int`.

If you want to scan small decimal numbers into small objects, then declare `num` as a `signed char` or an `unsigned char` and pair it with `%hhd` or `%hhu`, respectively.  If you want to scan a single character, not necessarily a decimal digit, then use `%c` (or use `getchar()` and skip `scanf` altogether).